Queues in C programming
This is the statement of the question (C programming):
A crowdsourcing system is a web platform through which various types of micro-tasks are made available, such as labeling images, annotating text snippets, translating parts of documents, or transcribing short audio clips, for users to perform, receiving economic compensation in return.
Imagine a crowdsourcing system that operates strictly under the "first come, first served" regime. A user of this system can choose to be assigned the task that has been on the platform the longest (whatever its type), or they can prefer to work on image labeling or document translation, and the system will assign them the task of that type that has been on the platform the longest. In no case can they choose the exact task to perform.
Implement in pseudocode the data structure that allows operating the system by developing operations such as enqueueTask, dequeueTask, dequeueTranslation, dequeueLabeling. Consider the case where there are no tasks of the selected type by the user.
Assume that the queue has unlimited capacity and that there exists a queue structure with its basic operations (init_queue, enqueue, dequeue, is_empty, first) already implemented and can be used directly. Represent tasks with a two-component structure, one variable of the string type to store the task name and another of long integer that stores a numeric timestamp indicating the date and time of task creation.
I tried to first create an structure with the task name and timestamp.
I don't know how to create a queue that differenciates these to types of tasks.

Use a separate queue for each type of task. The enqueueTask operation will need to know which queue to put a new task on. The dequeueTask operation will need to check all the non-empty queues and pick the one whose first item has the oldest timestamp.

You basically need two queues. The first queue would be storing everything, we'll call it the main queue and the second queue would only store tasks of "image labeling" and "document translation". It's unclear to me how the tasks would be created, but let's be agnostic and say that they are being somehow created, as the task was not very clear about the origin of these tasks.
Now, whenever a task is created, regardless of what type it is, we push_back this task to the main queue, the new task being added to the end of the line.
If this new task is one of our two special tasks, namely image labeling or document translation, then we push_back this task to the second queue too.
For all tasks we assign an id, which is ever increasing. So, whenever someone chooses to have a task of image labeling or document translation, then we pop this from the second queue and handle it.
Otherwise, if the user chooses to have a task performed from the main queue, then we have two cases:

the head of the main task that was popped is not image labeling or document translation: in this case we simply handle this task
or, the head of the main task is either image labeling or document translation. In this case we compare the id of the item we popped from the main queue and we have two cases:



The main queue is behind the secondary queue, in which case we ignore the current item and pop the next and proceed with this algorithm again




The main queue is in sync with the secondary queue, in which case we just need to make sure that the task is popped from both





If we have a series of tasks of the special image labeling or document translation nature at the head of the main queue and the main queue is being chosen, then we pop the head and ignore it until we either reach a non-special task, or the queues are empty or the two queues are in syn in terms of special tasks.
